# android : How to change name of the Enter key to "Search" with respect to particular EditText...?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to display 'Search' in place of 'Done' or 'Next' or symbol.
in the soft keyboard displayed when we click on any edit text....?

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Do you want it to only display a search icon, or should hitting the button actually perform an android-OS managed search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `imeOptions` attribute in the EditText:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) for other options. Note that not all keyboards support these, so it will be a "best effort" approach.